Can’t get exponential curve_fit to work with dates
I’m trying to plot a curve_fit for the S&P 500.
I’m successful (I think) at performing a linear fit/plot. When I try to get an exponential curve_fit to work, I get this error:
Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# get data
df = yf.download("SPY", interval = '1mo')
df = df.reset_index()

def func(x, a, b):
     return a * x + b
# ??     return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
# ??     return a*(x**b)+c
# ??     return a*np.exp(b*x)

# create data arrays
# convert Date to numeric for curve_fit ??
xdata = df['Date'].to_numpy().astype(np.int64)//10**9
ydata = df['Close'].to_numpy()

# p0 = (?, ?, ?) use guesses?
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

print(popt)

y_pred = func(xdata, *popt)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, y_pred, '-')
plt.show()


Am I dealing with dates correctly?
Should I be doing a p0 initial guess?
This question/solution may provide some clues.
It would be nice to have the x-axis labeled in a date format (but not important right now).

It's generally recommended to give it a good guess.

@jared   "a * np.exp(-b * x) + c"  seems to be a popular curve_fit function/model. My x data ranges from 728524800 to 1714521600. The y values range from 47 to 525. Can you recommend p0 values?

You have a huge additive constant in a date that destroys even moderate order polynomial fitting unless the fitting code is smart enough to rescale the problem onto [-1,1] whilst computing the fitting matrix. Your fit will be extremely unstable because of the huge additive constant making the fitting matrix very nearly singular. By eye the time for growth of exp(1) is about 8e+8 days and noisy.

@RandyPierson As Martin suggested, you should rescale your data. The ranges are too large for a curve fitter to accurately fit.

In addition to normalizing the data, it is important to actually choose a good function. In your example you had:
def func(x, a, b):
     return a * x + b
# ??     return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
# ??     return a*(x**b)+c
# ??     return a*np.exp(b*x)

The correct one, when you say you want to fit an exponential, should be this, IMO:
# define the exponential growth function, before you had exponential decay because of -b
def ExponentialGrowth(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c # + c due to account for offset

The power function might work as well, I did not check. Anyways, here's the code:
# define the exponential growth function, before you had exponential decay because of -b
def ExponentialGrowth(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c # + c due to account for offset
# get data
x = df['Date'].to_numpy().astype(np.int64)//10**9
y = df['Close'].to_numpy()
# apply z normalization
xNorm = (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
yNorm = (y - y.mean()) / y.std()
# get the optimal parameters
popt, pcov = curve_fit(ExponentialGrowth, xNorm, yNorm)
# get the predicted but in the normalized range
yPredNorm = ExponentialGrowth(xNorm, *popt)
# reverse normalize the predicted values
yPred = yPredNorm * (y.std()) + y.mean()
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['Date'], y, 1)
plt.plot(df['Date'], yPred, 'r-')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(["Raw", "Fitted"])
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Close")

And the results:

If you will eventually need to get initial guesses, you can search online how to get the initial guesses for any function. For example, if I am fitting an exponential growth function and I know that the data has an offset of 100, I can set the initial guess of c to a 100...
Hope this helps you.

Nice! I didn't know that curve_fit needs reasonably ranged data. Thank you for enlightening me to: normalization/de-normalization, keeping the x-axis date format, scatter, better coding style, etc.

@RandyPierson optimizers do not work with very small or very large values. It all lies with the calculations of the errors, the problem can be easily googled. I would like to note here that different fits might require different normalization techniques. E.g., if you are gonna go with a power fit -> use range norm instead of z norm to avoid having negative values.

This fit is a great start. Thank you for the range normalization suggestion for a power fit. I understand that I have some experimenting ahead of me. I'll research and experiment with different fit functions, range normalization, p0 guesses, etc.
